# Add has('vim_starting') in the start of .vimrc

Tags: vim

What is the reason of adding:

```
if has('vim_starting')
  set nocompatible
endif
```

In the start of a `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`has("vim_starting")` returns `true` on [startup](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#startup), `false` when running. The check is useful for the case when `.vimrc` is manually sourced with `:source ~/.vimrc` — it prevents execution of commands that have to be executed only once at startup.

Protecting `set nocompatible` is useful because the command also sets a lot of other options.

Comment: But if you have a `~/.vimrc` file, it will default to `'nocompatible'` by default, so this would not be needed for the regular configuration (only for those passed via `-u` or the system-wide one).